# How to reduce 36V 1.8A to 18V 1.2 A

Tags: power-supply

I have a power supply with 36V 1.8A, and I need to reduce this for my drill, which uses a 18V 1.2A battery. How can I lower the 36V from the power supply to the 18V that the drill accepts?

Comment: Are you sure that's a 1.2A battery, not a 1.2Ah battery? Big difference.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for is a *buck converter*.  That is a switching power supply that makes a lower voltage (and higher current) from a higher voltage (and lower current).  There are many chips available to do most of this for you.  You will have to provide the inductor and usually a few other parts.  Some chips require you to provide the switching element, others have them built in.

If this is meant to replace the battery in your drill, then it will probably work.  If you intend this to work together with the battery and even charge it, then it gets rather more complex and you can't just connect a fixed 18 V supply to the battery.

Comment: In his case, both the target voltage and current are actually lower than the source, which presumably gives some further options.

Comment: @micro: Not really.  It just means the buck converter won't draw the maximum 1.8 A from the 36 V supply.  However, the OP talks of a "1.2 A" battery, which means he doesn't know what he's talking about and we don't know what the current requirement at 18 V really is.

Answer (score 2):

There are a wide variety of switching converters you can use to convert your 36V power supply to 18V.

However you must understand that you are going to be disappointed with the result.  With 36V @ 1.8A going in, you're going to be driving that drill motor with, at most, 65W assuming a perfect converter.

Most decent [cordless drill motors](http://www.google.com/search?q=18v%20drill%20motor%20wattage) top out at around 400W.  The battery pack in your drill can deliver at least 20A under a stall condition when fully charged, leading to a driving wattage of 360W.

Even with a perfect power converter your drill is going to seem very, very weak with only 20% of the power it would normally be used to.

If you want a corded drill, get a corded drill that doesn't require a separate 400W power supply.  It'll be cheaper and easier.

If, for the sake of discussion, you decide you really do only need 50W of power to the drill motor, and you can't choose another corded drill, you can buy converters off-the-shelf for this job, or you can design one based on the many, many switching converter chips available today. [Off the shelf 50W 36V --> 18V converters aren't cheap](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/VE-BWN-EY/VE-BWN-EY-ND/2871273), but successfully building a high performance one yourself when you have little electronics experience might be unrewarding.